# React Testing Library .toHaveTextContent exact match

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

How do I make `expect(stuff).toHaveTextContent(text)` pass only when the text matches exactly?

`.toHaveTextContent("1")` counts as a match if the text I'm testing is "100"

Comment: `toEqual('100')`

Comment: @underscore I tried this, but it checks the text with all its HTML tags. 

So .toEqual('100') would compare '<div htmltags....>100</div>' with '100'

Answer (score 15):

You can do the ff instead:

```
expect(stuff.textContent).toBe('100')
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a regex instead `expect(stuff).toHaveTextContent(/^100$/);` if you want to match exactly.

As written in the doc (https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavetextcontent), it will (just) "check whether the given node has a text content or not"

Comment: Useful, but use caution. `.toHaveTextContent(/^My name is Joe. Hello, world.$/)` probably doesn't do what you expect (`.` is a regex special character matching any character rather than a period, so `My name is JoeZ Hello, world0` matches).

Answer (score 1):

Use `getByText` like so,

```
const { getByText } = render(<YourComponent />)

expect(getByText('text you\'re looking for')).toBeInTheDocument()
```

This assumes it *will be there*, so if there's a chance it won't be, use `queryByText`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the the text using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```
const element = await waitFor(() => document.querySelector('<YOUR_QUERY>'));

expect(element.innerHTML).toEqual('100')
```

Comment: What's the point of `waitFor`? There's nothing async here yet. Also, just because you're using `innerHTML` (probably better to use `textContent`) doesn't mean you should stop using RTL selectors. Even if there is an async query, seems best to use `screen.findByTestId` or similar, which does the waiting for you.

Answer (score 0):

As [yatrix shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68295555/6243352), `getByText` offers a non-substring semantic, but running it on the whole component as shown in that answer can lead to false positives. I'd prefer a precise test that checks whether a specific element has certain text:

```js
import React from "react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import {render, screen, within} from "@testing-library/react";

const {getByTestId} = screen;

describe("Test", () => {
  it("should be precise when testing text", () => {
    render(
      <div>
        <div data-testid="test1">10</div>
        <div data-testid="test2">100</div>
      </div>
    );
    expect(within(getByTestId("test1")).getByText("10"))
      .toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByTestId("test2")).toHaveTextContent(/^100$/);
  });
});
```

I've also tossed in an assertion using [Benjamin's regex approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73298371/6243352) but I'm wary of this since it's all too easy to forget you're in regex mode and fail to escape a special character like `.`.

Note also that

```js
expect(within(getByTestId("test1")).getByText("10"))
  .toBeInTheDocument();
```

can be simply:

```js
within(getByTestId("test1")).getByText("10");
```

because `getBy` will throw if it fails to find a matching element, effectively acting as an expectation/assertion. Kent [recommends keeping it explicit](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-get-variants-as-assertions), but also says it "really is fine honestly" to skip the assertion. Use `queryByText` for assertions for non-existence.

---

Relevant packages for this post:

```
{
  "@testing-library/dom": "8.11.1",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
  "@testing-library/react": "12.1.2",
  "@testing-library/react-hooks": "7.0.2",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
  "jest": "27.4.5",
  "jest-environment-jsdom": "27.4.4",
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "17.0.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best is to use a regular expresion.
Let say that you have:

```
const text = "My exact\ntext";
```

So the `RegExp` should be:

```
const escapePattern = new RegExp('[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]', 'g');
const replaceWith = '\\$&';
const textEscaped = text.replace(escapePattern, replaceWith);
const options = {
  normalizeWhitespace: false,
};
const regexpToHave = new RegExp(`^${textEscaped}$`, 'm')
expect(stuff).toHaveTextContent(regexpToHave, options);
```

The `m` string means "multiline" and the g "global".
Check the `options` and make sure set `normalizeWhitespace` to `false` to avoid issues.

It is common use in Jest to use `getByTestId`, and use `data-testid` attribute in the element to be tested. That you ensure that the correct element has the text and not other.